# How to Debug Network Errors (Specifically ICMP)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking, udp

I have a server/client type app, Wireshark shows that the client has sent a packet to the server, the server had given the expected response but shows a ICMP Destination port unreachable error.

I'm using a function that was on the MDSN website which has worked for me before.

EDIT: To update I have checked that the packet is being sent after the phone has started listening, I have tried other ports. There is no socket exception so i'm just looking for the best way to go about debugging network errors.

Any ideas?

```
public string Receive()
    {
        string response = "Operation Timeout";



        // We are receiving over an established socket connection
        if (udpSocket != null)
        {
            // Create SocketAsyncEventArgs context object
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(SERVER, RECIVEPORT);

            // Setup the buffer to receive the data
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE], 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
            // Note: This even handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                {
                    // Retrieve the data from the buffer
                    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                    response = response.Trim('\0');
                }
                else
                {
                    response = e.SocketError.ToString();

                }

                _clientDone.Set();
            });

            // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
            _clientDone.Reset();

            // Make an asynchronous Receive request over the socket
            Debug.WriteLine("Listening now:" + DateTime.Now.Second + ":" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("No socket exception");
                udpSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(socketEventArg);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.SocketErrorCode);
            }

            // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
            // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
            _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        }
        else
        {
            response = "Socket is not initialized";
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ICMP Destination port unreachable" means that there was no application bound to the port you were sending to.  Make sure that your `sendto()` is targeting to correct IP address and port number.  Also check that your listener is calling `bind()` on `INADDR_ANY` and the correct port.  A common mistake is to forget to convert the port number to network byte order (big-endian).  See `htons()`.